# Java SSH Client like PuTTy

Tags: java, ssh

So, I want to create my own SSH Client, not just sending commands but a full on ssh client for me to use like you would use PuTTy or mobaxterm, can someone here point me in the right direction.

Things I tried / thought of:
 - Using Jsch to send and execute commands (If its possible I would love to know if this is able to be done without using Jsch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH is a protocol that is defined to run on top of TCP, and you can make TCP connections in java using the `java.net.Socket` class.

So, yes, it can be done.

You'd have to implement the protocol yourself (or use JSch to do it, but given that all these tools already exist, and it's security, where in general relying on widely used tools is orders of magnitude more intelligent than relying on hand-written stuff, given that a security bug is *very* hard to test for – I assume this is some sort of exercise in sheer dogged arrogance, or, more likely, a learning exercise, which'd mean that you wouldn't want to use jsch here).

ssh works by sending any number of streams across the network, encrypted. By default, there is one stream (a two-way stream), with the user's shell being on one end (so, the `/bin/bash` executable, for example), and a terminal (where what you type forms the input, and any output is echoed to the terminal window) on the other.

ssh does NOT wait for you type a command then run it; that's `/bin/bash` doing this. This is basic linux info and has no direct bearing on ssh (the protocol), that's just what you're used to, because sshd (the linux executable that forms an ssh server) by default hooks your terminal up to the target server's shell executable. Usually bash.

Given that you know nothing of this, this sounds like a project that's a bit too far fetched as a starter experiment, but I'm going by incomplete information to make this assessment.

I'd start by making a trivial telnet client and server. telnet is at this point extremely outdated but it is basically ssh without the multiplexing of streams nor the encryption. If you can't write a telnet client, you can't write an ssh client either. And you can still start telnet servers on linux machines for testing purposes.

Once you've got that down, start figuring out the crypto and the multiplexing*.

*) With ssh you can, whilst having a shell open, also port forward and such; check out the `-R` and `-L` and `-D` options in standard ssh. Each such option allows for another stream to be sent along. (whilst you're sending shell commands and seeing their results, at the same time, over the same ssh connection, you are, say, sending a print job to a printer in the network of the other machine). Sending multiple streams through a single connection is called 'multiplexing', and it is part of the ssh specification.